# How can I query on a custom content entity base fields?

Tags: 8

I am trying to write a entityQuery and add condition on the base fields I've defined.

The query:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('map_object')
    ->condition('body', 'Test')->execute();
```

And the error:

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryException: 'body' not found in Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Tables->ensureEntityTable() (line 316 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php).
```

The definition:

```
    $fields['body'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('text_long')
      ->setLabel(t('Body'))
      ->setDescription(t(''))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'text_textfield',
        'weight' => 9,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

The column "body" does exists in the entities base table.

Comment: try to reinstall your module

Comment: Try running `drush entity-updates`

Comment: The entity needs no updates it says. @Clive

Comment: Reinstalling module didn't work either @AdrianCidAlmaguer

Comment: drush entity-updates is no more working with drupal 8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing `data_table` in the Entity annotation. By adding that and update the entity it allowed me to query as expected.

```
 *   base_table = "map_object",
 *   data_table = "map_object_field_data",
```